# Hibernate, OneToOne inverse side property not fetched when query for multiple entities

Tags: spring, hibernate

Inverse side:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "servers")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
public class Server {
  private Plan plan;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="server")
  public Plan getPlan() { return plan; }
}
```

Owner side:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "plans")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
public class Plan {
  Server server;

  @OneToOne(optional=false)
  @JoinColumn(unique=true, nullable=false)
  @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
  public Server getServer() { return server; }
}
```

Now I'm in

```
@Repository public class ServerDao extends org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport {}
```

When I try:

```
getHibernateTemplate().get(Server.class, 1);
```

the "plan" propery is loaded correctly. But when I'm trying to find multiple servers:

```
getHibernateTemplate().find("from Server");
```

the list of servers is returned, and each item has "plan" property set to null. What I'm doing wrong?

spring-orm:3.2.2.RELEASE
Hivernate 3.5.6-Final

Comment: Did you set both sides Server and Plan to point to each other, i.e. server.setPlan(plan); and plan.setServer(server);, or you just set the owning side?

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions come to my mind:

a. Try setting `optional` to `false` at `Server` side:

```
@OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy="server")
public Plan getPlan() { return plan; }
```

b. If you can change schema - move your join column to your `Server` class.

Have you looked at produced SELECT query?

Comment: One of other fields in Plan had nullable=false, but actually can be null (and was itself). This fact leads to "inner join" clause in one of hibernate generated SQL sub-query. After changed it to nullable=true life becomes better. Thanks!